# get max value in a list of struct C#

Tags: c#

i have a list of struct in c#.
the struct has 5 variables(int doc1,int paragraph1,int doc2,int paragraph2,float similarity).
doc1 , paragraph1 represent index of paragraph in doc is related with parag2 in doc2 by this similarity value.
It is possible that a paragraph in a document is associated with many other paragraphs with different similarity.
i want to have parag2 and doc2 having max similarity.

Comment: You could find something useful here http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/06/custom-c-3.0-linq-max-extension-method.aspx

Comment: some real code please. Else it would be like firing in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

[Override the operators ==, >, >=, <, <=, !=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) on the struct, then [use LINQ to get the max value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) from the list.